# How to dismiss popover View controller on iPad on tapping outside the view : IOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, ios9, uigesturerecognizer

i m trying to present a view controller as popoverviewcontroller using modal style of type .pagesheet. Here i m trying to add a tap gesture recognizer to dismiss this popoverviewcontroller on clicking ouside its view. But it is not detecting tap in iOS 9. Here is the code below of gesture recognizer

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let recog : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action:#selector(HandleTap))
        recog.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        recog.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        recog.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        recog.delegate = self
        self.view.window?.addGestureRecognizer(recog)

    }


func HandleTap(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void
{
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended)
    {
        var location : CGPoint = sender.locationInView(self.presentingViewController?.view)
        //var location : CGPoint = sender.locationInView(self.view?.window)
        if(!(self.view.pointInside(self.view.convertPoint(location, toView: self.view?.window), withEvent: nil)))
        {
          self.view.window?.removeGestureRecognizer(sender)
          self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `userinteractionenable` to `true` on `view` on which you handle the tap. and second thing why you are doing your stuff in `viewDidAppear`? You should use `viewDidLoad` to add gesture recognizer.

**Update :**

```
self.view.window?.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

if you are using navigation controller then

```
self.navigationController?.view.window?.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

hope thiw will help :)

Comment: userInteraction is already enabled on the view through .xib file.

Comment: if you are adding gesture recognizer to window then you should enable userinteraction to window. from .xib you can enable for view only

Comment: and put print statement in `handleTap` so you can know that method is getting called or not.